# Running a r-function in Rscript

Tags: r, docker

I have a custom R package build. It has a function that accepts an argument and outputs a result. I want to run it using `Rscript` and pass arguments to it. I am setting up the function as follows:
Example:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
add_fun <- function(x,y){

  result= x+y
  print(result)
}

add_fun(args[1], args[2])
```

When I invoke just the function

```
add_fun <- function(x,y){

  result= x+y
  print(result)
}
```

in my Rstudio and `add_fun(6,7)` I get the correct answer of `13`. But when I use `Rscript --vanilla add_fun.R --args 6 7`
I get the following message:

```
Error in x + y : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Calls: add_fun
Execution halted
```

Any thoughts on what I might be messing up in the `Rscript` call?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trying more options...I found the correct call to be

```
Rscript --vanilla add_fun.R  6 7
```

I also had to do an `as.integer(x) + as.integer(y)` in the function, as it appears `Rscript` call makes the numbers a character.

Just posting for everyone's benefit! Thanks!